# Declare char array in static class

Tags: c#, static

I want to declare a hex decimal value as a constant character with in a static constants class as shown below:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public char[] Record_Separator = new Char[] { '\x01E' };  //Record Separator
}
```

I know within a static class it's not possible to instantiate char as I wanted to retain all constants with in a single class so want to know if there is another way to do the same.

Comment: I think this is C#, though I don't know if Java is capable of this as well.

Comment: Can some one moderator remove java and put C# in Tag it was by mistake I selected java.

Comment: `Upper_Camel_Case` ? I'm not sure I've encountered this before and I'm not sure I like it...

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static readonly char[] Record_Separator = new Char[] { '\x01E' };  //Record Separator
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Constants {
    public static final char[] RECORD_SEPARATOR = { 0x1E };
}
```

Notes: Your constant should be `static` and `final`, otherwise it's not a constant. You've used `Char` instead of `char`. The common naming convention for `static final` constants in Java is `ALL_UPPERCASE`.

You cannot make a top-level class `static`.

Comment: it cannot be defined static, but it can be final with a private constructor

Comment: The question is about C#, not Java. ;-) I won't downvote, though :-D

Comment: Pfff... ;-) @ebeeb by the way, I didn't downvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
private const double MyConst = 0x01E;
```

What about this?

Comment: Why `double`?? The question is about Java, not C#.

Comment: You obviously popped in, when the the question was already retagged with java. The only tag was `static`

Comment: Well I have come up with a workaround for this issue i.e. decalring the all the varible static rathere class. But this doesn't seem to be good practise can somebody comment on this and suggest the best approach.

 public  class Constants
 {
         public static string n1="abc";
         public static string nn="abn";
         public static char[] Segment_Separator = new Char[] { '\x01E' }; 
 }


public static class Constants
{
    public const string n1="abc";
    public const string nn="abn";

}

Answer (score 0):

How about just using the static constructor?